How do you export client certificate for Android to make it work with server?
I posted here earlier today regarding my certificate issue. This is the last one I have. I have setup a new self-signed certificate chain with setup below by following this guide https://dev.to/berk/creating-fullchain-self-signed-ssl-root-intermediate-ca-3cb8:

Root CA

Intermediate CA

Server cert
Client1 cert





Now for the devices, we have:

Raspberry Pi - Server
PC (Arch) - Client1
Android (Phone) - Client1

What was the setup process:

We create fullchain certificate (Server -> Intermediate -> Root) and use it within webserver with server.key
1.1 We copy only the RootCA.crt to PC and Android
1.2 Connectivity has been tested from PC and Android and both succeed. At this point in time, we do not enforce client certificates

We enforce client certificates using lighttpd


    ssl.verifyclient.activate = "enable"
    ssl.verifyclient.enforce = "enable"
    ssl.verifyclient.depth = "10"
    ssl.verifyclient.ca-file = "/etc/lighttpd/ssl-rsa/CA/ca.crt"


Connection drops for both PC and Android.
We create fullchain certificate (Client -> Intermediate -> Root - cat client1/client.crt >> fullchain_client.crt && cat intermediateCA/intermediate.crt >> fullchain_client.crt && cat CA/ca.crt >> fullchain_client.crt) and name it fullchain_client.crt
We create fullchain pem cat fullchain_client.crt client.key > fullchain_client_crt_key.pem
We use it as such (PC) - curl https://192.168.1.218 --cert fullchain_client_crt_key.pem. This appears to work again and we can connect successfully.
For Android however, we cannot use the same file - fullchain_client_crt_key.pem because it works with p12 extensions instead.
For Android we attempt to create as such openssl pkcs12 -export -out fullchain_client_crt_key.p12 -in fullchain_client.crt -inkey client.key

However after moving the p12 file to Android and installing the p12 from Settings for both WiFi and App&VPN, it still fails to connect with message:
Read error: ssl=0xb40000710709b7d8: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
error: 1000045c:SSL
routines:OPENSSL_internal:TLSV1_ALERT_CERTIFICATE_REQUIRED(/usr/local/google/home/prb/src/boringssl/ssl/tls_record.cc:594 0xb400006f570bbab8:0x00000001)

I am using the HTTP Shortcuts Android app  to test connectivity.
Was there a mistake by how I generated the p12 key file, should it be any different? I can't really  infer anything from this error message apart that certificate is required, that I already installed. I think I'm doing something wrong but I don't know where or what
I restarted android App too after applying certificates, but no effect
If anyone knows what could be the issue, please comment

I confirmed that using the same file fullchain_client_crt_key.p12 for Firefox (importing into app manually) on PC works. It's just Android that is complaining

On Android 13/14 you need to add -legacy to the export command:
openssl pkcs12 -export -legacy -out fullchain_client_crt_key.p12 -in fullchain_client.crt -inkey client.key

